# dynamically creating 2-D arrays with default values in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a c++ way to create dynamically create a 0 initialized 2-D integer array ? (Something like using calloc() in c)

Comment: You can use `calloc()` in C++, too. However, for matrices, there is a bunch of better solutions, just search for "C++" and "matrix".

Comment: Please specify which of the dimensions are known at compile-time (if any)

Answer (score 0):

Add a pair of brackets after basic types when dynamically create it lead to make it zero.

For example,

```
int* a = new int();
int* b = new int;
```

then *a == 0, *b == !#$%#$@$%&

The same to array,

```
int* a = new int[5]();
int* b = new int[5];
```

I guess you have known what happened to them new.

So this trick could be used to 2D array as well. You can try writing like this

```
int (*a)[10] = new int[5][10]();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no Standard construct for a contiguous 2-D array with runtime dimensions accessible by `[][]`.  If this is what you want, then download a Matrix library. (If you are feeling brave then you could try writing your own).

To make a jagged array you can write:

```
vector<vector<int>> arr1{r, vector<int>(c)};
```

where `r` and `c` are the dimensions.